# Highchart how to create lollipop type chart with circle and line top/bottom at different positions

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking for chart to show series with high low and average. High/Low reflected by the y coordinate of the high/low values, and a circle at the y coordinate of the average. [image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this using highcharts (in reactjs)?

Thanks,
Reuven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to achieve that is to add each of the category group as a separate series and add dynamically the average point for the group.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ytfquvhg/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this;

        chart.series.forEach(s => {
          let avrPoint = s.yData.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / s.yData.length
          s.addPoint({
            y: avrPoint,
            x: s.points[0].x,
            marker: {
              enabled: true
            },
            name: 'average'
          })
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Hi Sebastian, i was remiss in adding another important element - the other charts in our application are stockCharts, and having the date rangeSelector is expected. For this chart I'm using candlestick, trying to replace the open/close with a single circle. I've used your logic (thanks!) to add the avg point - this works, but it appears as a box. Is it possible to render the open/close as a circle? Or suppress them, and add a circle after the load? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, @ReuvenTrabin could you reproduce your case with a simple data example on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Here's simple version: https://jsfiddle.net/vn0zctsa/ note that the difference between the open and close values would represent the diameter of the circle. I may want to have that diameter reflect the number of transactions in some proportion.

Comment: I think that a much better solution is to use the 'columnrange' series type and add scatter points in the middle of it, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9upL10bc/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I agree, that's a cleaner solution. As I'm fairly new to reactjs and highcharts, I'm challenged getting both types of charts (also using stockchart) in the same component. Here's a snippet from my js file:

Comment: import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

class ChartHighstock extends Component {  ... }
...
componentDidMount() { this.createChart(); }
...
createChart() {
...
  var productActivityChart = Highcharts.stockChart('product-activity-chart', {...});

and this line throws this error: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=columnrange

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you reproduce your code on some online editor which I could work on? Here is a template which you can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-7d1nd

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, we need to do some refactoring to move to highcharts-react-official. Once we do, I think things will fall into place. Thanks for all your help - I'm marking your initial response as the accepted answer.